# Design optaplanner constraints of booking system

Tags: optaplanner

I would like to design a booking system using optaplanner, bellow my business model:

```
Customers (id, name) //Customer table
Services(id, name, description, duration)  //services that a customer can book, duration can be 15min, 30min, ..., N x 15min
Employees(id, name)  //Employee tables
Appointment(id, customerId, employeeId, serviceId, startTime, endTime)
```

To book an appointment, the customer will select:

- The day of the appointment (mandatory)
- A list of services (mandatory)
- A list of employees (optional)

I would like to know I can design the model to return the list of availability for a given day, given list of services.
Bellow a basic pseudo-code model :

```
@Entity
public class Service extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    private int durationInGrains;
}

public class TimeGrain  {

    public static final int GRAIN_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES = 15;

    private int grainIndex; // unique
    private int startingMinuteOfDay;
}


@Entity
public class Employee extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @PlanningId
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Appointment extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    private Employee employee;
    private Service service;

    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
}

@PlanningEntity
public class Availability {

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "timeGrainRange" })
    private TimeGrain startingTimeGrain;
    
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "providerRange")
    private Provider provider;
    
    private Service service;
}

@PlanningSolution
public class AppointmentAvailability {

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeGrainRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<TimeGrain> timeGrainList;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "providerRange")
    private List<Provider> providerList;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "appointmentsRange")
    private List<Appointment> appointmentList;
    
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Availability> availabilityList;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardMediumSoftScore score;
}
```

As I am new to optaplanner, could you please advise if this is the way to go?

***UPDATE 1*:** *I have simplified the problem to the minimum for design purposes.*

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I have the same exact problem and I'm evaluating optaplanner as well.

Comment: I finally didn't use optiplanner, just some algorithm but if you have ideas how it can be solved, I am happy to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **meeting scheduling** example in `optaplanner-examples`, to get inspired on how to model it. Also see the **Time Grain pattern** in the docs in the section Design Patterns. The school timetabling quickstart follows the Timeslot pattern instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this will assign automatically available timeslot to the customer, what I would like is to be able to display available timeslots to the user for a given date and a given service, the customer then will choose, and the booking will be saved into the database, and the corresponding timeslot won't be available anymore to anyone else.

Comment: by the way, is a booking system a good use case for optaplanner? if the day is fixed, list of services and/or preferred employees, then the question is to find available timeslots by employee to show to the customer,  minimize delays between services, make sure not to select employee on holidays, etc. Again thank you very much for your help

Comment: A booking system is a good use case for optaplanner if and only if you can assign multiple bookings in the same solve() call. If you need to assign one booking per solve() call, so for example if clients call in for a booking, give their constraints and need to know immediatly when that booking is, then optaplanner is overkill. There is no massive optimization gain to be made if all but 1 booking is pinned. A simple decision table (see drools) will do in that case. But in the other case, optaplanner is perfect.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but what happens I have more business complex rules like a customer can have multiple services but gaps between then should be less than X minutes or some services can be done in parallel or service duration depends on the employee? does this justify to use optaplanner?  Obviously, slover should have a time response of a second or two as it is real-time app

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet would appreciate an answer to his most recent comment.

Comment: @Sam Don't assign a booking to a start time, but a start time windows. Convince/prove to your business that you can greatly increase efficiency that way. Give yourself the room for optimization. Then use OptaPlanner. Telco have been doing it for years. You don't get an appointment that your technician will arrive at 9:32. No, you get an appointment that he/she will arrive between 9:00 and 11:00. How big you can make the time window depends on the service.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet the problem is that I am working for a business where the nature of the business is that people come in, which means that I can't necessarily tell them that they can come in at 9:00 AM and will be seen some time between then and 11:00 AM, or whatever time window.

Comment: Then optimization is limited. OptaPlanner is a bit overkill atm, but running an OptaPlanner Construction Heuristic with a single unpinned entity will still take advantage of increment scoring etc. We should probably support these use cases with a specific API too.

Comment: I released how to make appointments more efficient: think of the employees as "scheduled"/on-call for every slot/shift, and with each shift associate a name and whatever information goes along with a client, and reschedule the employees instead of the client. This way it will find the most efficient schedule for the employees to match the client's needs. Thisnwqy, you can assign multiple shifts in one solve() call. @GeoffreyDeSmet what do you think?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet what do you think of my previous comment? Also, would there be a way to present a list of available times to the client for when appointments are available, sorted by the most optimized/profitable Appointment first? That would probably give more leeway for optimization.